# Java runtime vs OS calls

Tags: java, operating-system, runtime

The Java runtime provides a set of standard system libraries for use by programs. To what extent are these libraries similar to the system calls of an operating system, and to what extent are they different???

Answer (score 4):

Half the point of java was to make it platform independent, so what it tries to do is provide an api that remains the same regardless of the OS underneath it.

If the OS is underpowered, Java will add library code to compensate for it.

If the OS has an implementation that doesn't map, Java will do it's best to map it.

If a new function becomes popular and Java users need to provide access to it, a new library can be created through which you can access the new functionality.  If this library is popular, it will be restructured and added into the Java SDK at some point

For instance, an implementation of some concurrency libraries became popular, and soon they were voted upon and added to the standard libraries.  This happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

That obviously depends on the OS you're running on, since the system calls are generally different for every OS :-).

That said, I believe Java was mostly inspired by Unix conventions (not surprinsingly, as Sun is a Unix vendor), so some Java system libraries are similar to Unix sytem calls.

E.g. java.nio.MappedByteBuffer was probably inspired by Unix's mmap() call. But ultimately most concepts are present on most OSes, so you cannot really say what inspired what.

Answer (score 0):

Some of Java's "low-level" functions are basically "wrappers" around some OS
system calls.

I don't see an objective way (and reason) to "compare" both.

If you are interested in this topic, you can search the Java source code
for the **native** keyword, which indicates some "hidden"
(mostly OS-dependend) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Java's standard library often has a similar feature set compared to the native library but there are several important differences.

1. Java is Object Oriented, whether you like it or not. The advantage of this is that certain concepts are easier to manage.  For example, most file related operations are found directly in the File object.  Compare this to Posix, where a FILE is a handle which is really just a number; an index into your process's open file list.  The Posix approach is very close to how the OS actually implements stuff.  But in Java you don't see that or know it or care.
2. Java has certain lowest-common-denominator behaviours in certain cases.  There are many AWT APIs that are the way they are because AWT needed to be identical on a number of separate platforms.  That turned out to be madness, and Sun quasi-deprecated most of AWT, because supporting platform equally meant supporting every platform crappily.  The newer library, Swing, implements almost everything in pure Java, and thus is far better at cross-platform stuff, and thus has a richer API.  And that API is very different from the native windowing library.  Also, Swing doesn't integrate too well because it uses so little of the native OS.
3. Java has certain limitations that the native libraries don't have.  For example, you don't have function pointers.  Thus you have `Listeners` and `Runnable` and other Java patterns for doing things that in C++ would involve function pointers.  So any API that needs one of these features will be significantly different in Java than in the native OS.

So in conclusion, Java often has libraries that offer similar behaviour to the native OS, and sometimes offer completely different behaviour, but it's best to think of Java as a platform in its own right.  Sometimes you need advanced performance, such as OpenGL or super-fast data transfer, in which case you'll want a specific Java API (Jogl, nio), but most of the time you should evaluate Java as its own thing.